# Issue on Loading Google Map - SensorNotRequired

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to run Google Map on a WordPress site. The code is running perfectly on this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3VKQ8/55/) but when I take it to WordPress I am getting this error

> Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired:
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

I also tried this code

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3"></script>
```

but the result is same.

Finally I tried to get a key from API and use it

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

and now I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: window.initMap is not a function

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3"></script>
```

Try:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

From the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages):

> The sensor parameter is no longer required for the Google Maps
>   JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps JavaScript API from
>   working correctly, but we recommend that you remove the sensor
>   parameter from the script element.

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge but can you also let me know what was wrong with the other scripts?

Comment: Yes in the first script you have an improper sensor=true and if you don't need sensor omit this clause is better, in the second script invocke a callback function named initMap but this function in not present in your code so you get the error. I hope this is useful