# jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete with Google Maps API - geocomplete

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, geolocation

My Javascript/Jquery knowledge is not great to be honest but im hoping someone can help me out.

I am trying to implement an auto complete feature into my website which allows users to begin typing a location into an input field and the auto complete kicks in with matching places. I have stumbled across a JQUERY plugin called [jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete with Google Maps API - geocomplete](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Geocoding-Places-Autocomplete-with-Google-Maps-API-geocomplete.html) and i am having a difficult time getting it to work.

Here is what i have

A web form that looks like this

[image]

input text html as follows

```
        <!--Location fieldset-->
        <fieldset class="form-group location">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Location</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="geocomplete" class="locationsearch location form-control" type="text" value="" name="geocomplete" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

and in my homepage template i have added teh following script and references like it says to do so for basic usage

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete()});
</script>
```

I am unable to get the auto complete feature to work and i really dont know why?

Sorry if the answer in obvious

Many thanks

Edit* Please see the errors that i am receiving in the browser console

[image]

Further Edit *I fixed the JQUERY reference errors - this was occurring because i was trying to call the jQuery ref before I even loaded jQuery into the page. The issue i have now is i am using two multiple google API's on the same page. I am using one for google maps & one to auto complete the location input field. How can i combine these? They are as follows

Auto Complete =

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Google Map =

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initGoogleMaps" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: [The posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q904vfy0/), do you see any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply. I have added an image to my original post to display the errors in the console. It would appear that there is a confilt as i am also using the google maps api. How would i resolve this issue please?

Comment: i have fixed the JQUERY reference errors. I was trying to call jquery ($) before the jquery library had been loaded on to the page. However, i still have an issue with the error relating to 'you have included google Maps API multiple times on this page'. I have the following two scripts Auto Complete = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>' Google Map = '<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initGoogleMaps" type="text/javascript"></script>'

Answer (score 1):

With a fresh head i have now resolved this issue.

First i had to make sure that the JQUERY library was referenced correctly on my web page before i attempted to create a function and call jquery($).

To solve the issue with the 'you have included google Maps API multiple times on this page'. Instead of calling the google API twice with different parameters i simply added appended them as so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=initGoogleMaps"></script>
```

Full code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#location").geocomplete({
            details: ".geo-details",
            detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
        });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initGoogleMaps"></script>
```

Note you dont need the sensor=false parameter = [Issue on Loading Google Map - SensorNotRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321883/issue-on-loading-google-map-sensornotrequired)

Result ;)

[image]

Please let me know if this can be improved.

Paul

Comment: How did you get the API_KEY?